# tic tac toe javascript reset button not working

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to create a reset function - I have created a for loop that basically on click will take the values that are in "input" class and return an empty string.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function reset (){
    for (i=0 ; 1 < cell.length ; i ++){
        document.getElementsByClassName("input").addEventListener("click").value =""
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to create an event handler (click) to every input tag? Or do you have only one button outside of the table, which should do the reset? Please clear up your description of your question and provide the corresponding HTML!

Answer (score -1):

```
getElementsByClassName
```

returns an array. You need to specify an index. ie. classArray[i]. Also, you forgot a semi colon at the end of the line.